# Why can't I use more than 1 gb of ram?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Why does my allocated ram on Minecraft stay at 1GB? On the launcher it is set to 2GB but ingame it is just 1GB. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post your JVM settings from your launcher?

Answer (score 2):

Your Java version is likely to be 32 bit. Download Java 64 bit [on this page](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp).